# Can Accept-Ranges Be Enabled On Ruby Cartridge

Tags: ruby, openshift-online-2

I'm running Padrino on a Ruby cartridge. I have an application that serves a somewhat large mp3 file to be consumed by an in-browser player, so I need to send a Range Request. If I don't, the file stops playing and basically craps out until I make a new request, but the same thing always happens with each request.

I set up the route to explicitly return a 206 code for the file. This fixed the problem reliably on my local stack, however the Openshift server responds with this header: 'Accept-Ranges:none.' From what I have read, this means the server does not support Range Requests.

Is there any way for me to enable this? I couldn't find any information about it, although I saw that Node cartridges have had this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is a [known bug in OpenShift](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1127925). I suggest you add your name to the bug, and also contact Red Hat Support if you are using OpenShift Enterprise.

Comment: Thanks! I did see that bug report but thought it was just for the Node cartridge. I added my comment.